# Visual Studio Team Services - How to copy built Windows service files To Azure VM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am trying to run Visual Studio Team Services automated build and deploy but having trouble with copying built windows service to Azure VM.

These are my steps:

**Build**
[image]

**Tried with Windows File Copy**
[image]

**Tried with Azure File Copy**
[image]

When I copy files from web projects (ASP.NET MVC 5) with Azure File Copy, everything works fine and the files are transfered. When I try to copy Windows Service built files, it failes silently. The task passes successfully but when I open the VM through remote desktop, the folder is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Service project is different with Asp.Net MVC project. With the arguments you specified in "MSBuild Arguments" of "Visual Studio Build" step, there is no file generated in "$(build.stagingdirectory)" folder. So "Azure File Copy" task just passed and copied nothing.

To fix this, changing the argument to following and then try the build again:

```
/p:outputpath="$(build.stagingdirectory)"
```